# How to pass any type of value to function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, types, option-type

So essentially, I want to be able to pass multiple parameters to a function. One of which will be optional and I would also like it to take any type of variable.

How can this be done, am I way off base with something like this:

```
public new object Session (String strSession, Type objValue = null)
{
    // Execute logic
}
```

**Or**

```
public new object Session <T> (String strSession, objValue<T> = null) 
{
    // Execute logic
}
```

**Don't see why this got down-voted. I provided clear code snippets didn't I?**

Comment: `object` or `dynamic` - not `Type` (if you want the first form).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use `object`, which is the base type for all .NET types, or use a generic method.

```
public new object Session (String strSession, object objValue = null)
{
    // Execute logic
}
```

Or

```
public new object Session<T> (String strSession, T objValue = default) 
{
    // Execute logic
}
```

Edit:

Since `T` can be any type, including value types (which cannot be `null`), `default` is more appropriate for the generic version.

I highly recommend the generic version because, for value types, the first version actually forces boxing to occur, which might be a performance issue.

Read more about boxing and unboxing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).